# can i use ffmpeg with actionscript to convert a webcam video flv into mp4?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, ffmpeg, mp4, flv

How can i use ffmpeg with actionscript to convert a webcam video flv into mp4?
I am not using any media server.

I am making webcam video using alchemy class, the output is a flv file, due to the "on disc size" of this flv I wish to export a MP4 from actionscript, someone suggested me that this can be achieved by using FFMPEG.

Can anyone help me in doing so, some source code or tutorial links, anything that helps me create a bridge between flash and ffmpeg for converting video on the fly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only option i can think of is to use Air and Nativeprocess as described here http://www.purplesquirrels.com.au/2013/02/converting-video-with-ffmpeg-and-adobe-air/

Otherwise I'm afraid this cannot be done unless someone does a port of FFMPEG to flash. The easiest way to do the video conversion you mention is to install FFMPEG on a server, send a request, and get the result back later.